# NodeJS retrieve JSON and serve to EJS template

Tags: json, node.js, express, ejs, fs

my purpose is to  get a JSON and serve it to an EJS file.

This is my code:

```
//server.js

users = require('./controllers/users.js');

global.app_root = path.resolve(__dirname);

app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
    res.render('partials/users', {
        data: users.retrieve_users
    });
})

//users.js

var fs = require("fs");

exports.retrieve_users = function (req, res) {
   fs.readFile(app_root + "/config/" + "users-list.json", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
      res.end(data);
   });
}

//users.ejs

<body>
   <%= data %>
</body>
```

But as output of this code inside the body I see literally this string:

```
'function (req, res) {
   fs.readFile(app_root + "/config/" + "users-list.json", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
      res.end(data);
   });
}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your data is coming asynchronous and you don't wait for them before the rendering. In fact right now you dont even run the `users.retrieve_users` function, you just getting back the function declaration and express renders it as string! Change your code to this.

```js
//server.js

users = require('./controllers/users.js');

global.app_root = path.resolve(__dirname);

app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
   
    //a method that get thr user-list data and renders it
    users.retrieve_users()
      .then(function(users){
         res.render('partials/users', {
            data: users
        });
      })
      .catch(function(err){
         res.status(500).send({ error: 'something blew up' });
      })
    
})

//users.js

var fs = require("fs");

exports.retrieve_users = function () {
   //function that returns user-list in promise
   return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
       fs.readFile(app_root + "/config/" + "users-list.json", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
          if(err) return reject(err)
          resolve(data);
       });
   })
  
}

//users.ejs

<body>
   <%= data %>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks man... Using your code it goes in error

`{"error":"something blew up"}`

Comment: make a `console.log(err)` inside the catch function

Comment: the output of this console.log is my JSON, I tried to edit 

`fs.readFile(app_root + "/config/" + "users-list.json", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
          if(err) return reject(err)
          reject(data);
       });`

to `reject(data)` -> `resolve(data)` but it print my user.ejs without content inside the `<%= data %>`

Comment: lol I have made many typo errors, check the answer now, maybe i am tired!

Comment: Thanks.. It works now.. The error was that you were passing two times the retrieve method? :D

Comment: the error was that i forgot to change `users.retrieve_users` function to the `users` variable that contains the actual data after the promise resolved.