# Passing info from psql to ejs using async

Tags: node.js, ejs

I want to pull from a PSQL database with pg and display the info into a table. I have been able to pull the data and display as an object (? all of the data displays with the endpoint that I used below to test) with promises and async but cannot work out how to send it to EJS to render.

```
//using async/await
router.route('/')
    .get(async function (req, res) {      
        try {
            let accountList = await createALb();
            res.send(accountList);
            //res.render('/accountList', {'accountList': accountList})
        }
        catch(err) {
            res.status(500).send(err)
        }
    });


async function createALb() {
    const client = await pool.connect()
    const data = await client.query(select)
    client.release()
    //console.log(data) - this is returning the object, it's working homie
    return data
    
}
   
module.exports = router;
```

server.js

```
const accountList = require('./pgpooling');
//const accountList = require('./accountList.json'); - I can access this info and manipulate into a table

//setup view engine
app.engine("ejs", ejsEngine);
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

//this is sending the right information
app.use('/accountList', accountList)

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.render("ejs/index");
});
```

Any time I try to access in EJS with:

```
<%- accountList.rows[0].account_name %>
```

or similar, it throws a "accountList is not defined" error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you see the view's content in the browser when going to the homepage? did you set the views `app.set('views', path)`

Comment: Yes, the views are set as above. I cannot send the data to the homepage but I can send it to http://localhost:3000/accountList

Comment: just remove the last 3 lines of codes where you define `app.get('/')` this one is for the index page, and then replace `app.use('/accoutList'` with `app.use('/')`

Answer (score 0):

I used the structure here [NodeJS retrieve JSON and serve to EJS template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47454970/nodejs-retrieve-json-and-serve-to-ejs-template) to call the function before sending it to the render and it worked. Figured it was something to do with the async code, frustrating it took me so long

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  accountList.createALb()
    .then(function(accountList){
      res.render("ejs/index", {
        'accountList': accountList})
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      res.status(500).send({error: 'we done homie'})
    })  
 });
```